# IBM MobileFirst 7.1: know if realm logout-function is explicitly invoked

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

Is there a way to know when the logout-function of the realm is explicitly invoked by the client with the `WL.Client.logout(<realm>)` or it’s triggered by Worklight itself(maybe for timeout)?

We would like to programmatically trace the cause of the logout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in to use to trace "the cause".

What you could do for user-triggered logout is to programmatically log the action in the logout function and use the analytics .send() to send this to the server and review it in the analytics console.

For other types of logout, such as token expiration, which typically happens if a used was logged in and then tried to access some secure resource but the token expired and then got hit with a challenge again, so if you can isolate that you can log it as well with a different analytics .send() message.

Comment: Thanks Idan but unfortunately in our configuration we don't have the Analytics service installed. Is there any other way to obtain some sort of calling stack related to the logout function?